# M365 Sharepoint People web part Details not updating from AD correctly

Tags: office-365, people-directory

It seems an eagle-eyed user found that when looking at the People web part in M365 Sharepoint, the person's job title is correct.  But when you look at the Organization tab of a person, the "works with" section is not updated correctly from AD.  Everywhere else within M365, seems to be updated correctly.

Figure 1:  The person's details, Overview tab.
[image: Figure 1 - The person's details, Overview tab]

Figure 2:  The person's details, Organization tab.
[image: Figure 2: The person's details, Organization tab.]

I guess it could be a lagging update, but it's been weeks since these were changed.

Please advise & Cheers,
Red
I know it's strange, but if anyone has see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a case into Microsoft over the past few weeks which they have confirmed back to me that titles not updating in the People Profiles web part is a known issue. They state it is something they are working on fixing, but there is no ETA at this time. Could be around for quite a while.

The only workaround is to just edit the web part and then delete and re-add the user(s) that need title to reflect correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would confirm that the person's manager value is set correctly in Azure Active Directory first. If it is indeed correct and SharePoint's User Profile Service is not synchronising this information or not in a timely manner, then I would create a support ticket with Microsoft. In SharePoint Online, we do not have control over the User Profile Synchronisation and therefore Microsoft will need to resolve an issue with your tenant. You can create a new service request via the Microsoft 365 admin portal. In the menu section, you'll see the "New service request" option within "Support".